# Количество значений в диапазоне, входящих в указанный интервал

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Имеется таблица со значениями от 0 до 45748.
Можно ли посчитать ВСЕ значения, входящие в интервал от 0 до 4575? Какие функции нужно использовать?

Гуглил, везде описывается только как найти определенное значение из таблицы, а не множество.

Comment: А что значит "выделить"? Можно их посчитать, сложить - это понятно, а выделить?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский то есть найти в таблице все значения, входящие в заданный интервал и, по возможности, внести число, соответствующее количеству этих значений в отдельную ячейку. Извиняюсь, сначала неправильно выразил мысль.

Comment: То есть посчитать их? Тогда это функция CЧЁТЕСЛИМН()

Comment: Да, подсчитать. Спасибо большое :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A2:F20;"<=4575")
```

Если в диапазоне есть значения больше и меньше нужных:

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A2:F20;">=5")-СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A2:F20;">4575")

=СЧЁТЕСЛИМН(A2:F20;">=5";A2:F20;"<=4575")    

=СУММПРОИЗВ(--(A2:F20>=5);--(A2:F20<=4575))
```

Со ссылками на ячейки:

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИМН(A2:F20;">="&A1;A2:F20;"<="&B1)
```